# How to negate a filter with JSONAPI requests in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, json-api

I'm trying to build a query that returns all items whose path do NOT contain a string.

I can easily build one that returns items whose path does contain a string:

```
GET /url?filter[path][CONTAINS]=string
```

But how can I negate that filter?

Comment: Does your api implement [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/)? Does your filtering strategy follow a specific specification? Or are you asking for filter strategies that support a negation, which you might want to implement?

Comment: Yes, the api implements the JSON:API specification (I am using Drupal and its JSONAPI module for the backend).
So yes, I am trying to figure out a filter strategy that support a negation.

Answer (score 3):

[JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/) itself is agnostic about the filtering strategy used. All it does is recommending that the query parameter `filter` is used for filtering:

> **Filtering**
>
> The `filter` query parameter is reserved for filtering data. Servers and clients **SHOULD** use this key for filtering operations.
>
> > Note: JSON:API is agnostic about the strategies supported by a server. The `filter` query parameter can be used as the basis for any number of filtering strategies.
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-filtering

But you mentioned in a comment that you are using Drupal's JSON:API. That one implements a well specified filtering strategy.

The filtering strategy used by Drupal is build around conditions, which could be grouped and combined either with *OR* or *AND*.

A condition is the combination of a path of fields, an operator and a value. [It's documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/filtering) lists the following operators as supported:

- `'='` (equal)
- `'<>'` (not equal),
- `'>'` (greater than)
- `'>='` (greater or equal than)
- `'<'` (less than)
- `'<='` (less or equal than)
- `'STARTS_WITH'`
- `'CONTAINS'`
- `'ENDS_WITH'`
- `'IN'`
- `'NOT IN'`
- `'BETWEEN'`
- `'NOT BETWEEN'`
- `'IS NULL'`
- `'IS NOT NULL'`

For most operators it supports their negated counter part - like `'in'` and `'not in'`, `'IS NULL'` and `'IS NOT NULL'`, `'<'` and `'>='`. But a few operators do not have a negated counterpart: `'CONTAINS'`, `'STARTS_WITH'` and `''ENDS_WITH'`. I guess that's cause it may be very expensive to do a search with a `'NOT CONTAINS'` operator on the supported databases.

As the documentation also doesn't mention a possibility to negate an condition or a group of conditions I think your specific use case is not support by Drupal's filtering strategy.